# strange behaviour in function Hoisting

Tags: javascript, scratchpad

I written below script and executed in scratch pad.

```
baz();

var baz = function(){
  console.log("Hello World");
}
```

When I try to execute above script, I got below kind of exception. I know, this expression comes because, hoisting is not valid for function expressions.

```
/*
Exception: TypeError: baz is not a function
@Scratchpad/1:1:1
*/
```

Now, I replaced the function name 'baz' with 'say_hello', and re run the application, it is working fine with no exception. Is there any reason for this behaviour?

```js
say_hello();

var say_hello = function(){
  console.log("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: say_hello is not a function`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, then there can be a problem in firefox scratch pad

Answer (score 1):

```js
say_hello();

function say_hello(){
  console.log("Hello World");
}
```

This is the one which is really **working fine with no exception**

The reason is:

> JavaScript only hoists declarations (variable and function declarations), not initializations

If a variable is declared and initialized after using it, the value will be undefined. For example:

```
console.log(num); // Returns undefined 
var num;
num = 6;
```

If you declare the variable after it is used, but initialize it beforehand, it will return the value:

```
num = 6;
console.log(num); // returns 6
var num;
```

For more information:[Only Declarations Are Hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#Only_declarations_are_hoisted)